# How to get autoload data from sub dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, php

I need to choose subcategory from first dropdown list. When i choose first dropdown, i need second dropdown appear when first dropdown is selected. Below is my code:

```css
<form action='' method="post">
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
     $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Could not connect to server.' );
    $conn = mysql_select_db('cattest', $link) or die('Could not select database.');

    ?>

    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Choose category : </td><td>
    <select id="cat">
    <?php
    $sql=mysql_query("select * from category");

    while($getcat=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
     
     $catid = $getcat['cid'];
     $catname = $getcat['cat'];
     
     echo "
      <option value='$catid'>$catname</option>

    ";
     
    }

    ?>
    </select>
    </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Choose subcategory : </td><td>
    <select id="sub">
    <?php
    $subsql=mysql_query("select * from sub where cid='$catid'");

    while($getsub=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
     
     $subid = $getsub['cid'];
     $subname = $getsub['cat'];
     
     echo "
      <option value='$subid'>$subname</option>

    ";
     
    }

    ?>
    </select>
    </td>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#cat').change(function() {
              $('.sub').hide();
              var v =  $('#cat option:selected').val();
              $('#sub_' + v).show();
        });
    });
    </script>
    </tr>
    </form>
```

please help. i think have an error on my javascript code.

Comment: your second dropdown has only had the id `sub` and by looking at your code, javascript will look for an element id of `sub_` appended by the value selected from the first dropdown id `cat` which points to nothing, I assumed you have an error in the console when you did a selection.

Comment: can you explain by code? just not understand it.